# MySQL Workbench com autocomplete com todas as colunas do banco quando uso alias de tabela

Tags: mysql, autocompletar

Percebi que depois que instalei uma nova versão do MySQL Workbench o autocomplete traz colunas de todas as tabelas, isso quando uso alias para tabela, quando repito o nome da tabela o autocomplete funciona normal. O problema é que às vezes o nome da tabela é bem extenso.

Exemplo:

```
SELECT * FROM cliente_relatorio_dinamico C where C.coluna_deste_banco;
```

Antes, ao apertar <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Espaço</kbd> depois do "C." aparecia somente colunas deste banco, agora mostra colunas de todos os bancos.

Acredito que tenha sobrescrito algum arquivo de configuração da versão antigo.

Tentei voltar à versão anterior mas não corrigiu.

Alguém tem alguma ideia ?

Comment: Boa tarde.
Percebi que o problema ocorre com o MariaDB e o Workbench com versão superior a 6.0.9, ou seja, se você está usando o MariaDB use a versão 6.0.9. No meu caso, mudei para Mysql e está resolvido.
Abraços.

Answer (score 1):

Tive problemas semelhantes com a versão 6.2.5, tive que fazer o downgrade para a versão 6.1.7 e o problema foi solucionado, comigo resolvi dessa forma, pode ser que seja uma alternativa pra vocês.